# How to export multiple sheets and save them in new created folder with same title as workbook

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, foreach, export

Tried to export worksheets to pdf with loop and save them in a newly created folder, the folder has the same name as the active workbook. Code worked in the previous file but now it won't loop anymore or save in the new folder. It creates the folder and it exports the active sheet to pdf nothing else.

When I run it I get runtime error 5 but only when I let it run as loop

I have already tried different filenames (active workbook.path & "\" &) and different ways to create a new folder (MkDir)

```
Sub ExportAsPDFAndSaveInNewFolder()

    Dim wbA     As Workbook
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim tdate As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fldrName As String
    Dim fldrpath As String

    Dim myFile  As String

    Dim CF As Long, CV As Long, RF As Long, RV As Long
    Dim Col As Long, Rw As Long
    Dim path As String

    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult

    ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.
    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet
    tdate = "Dec"

    'create new folder
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        fldrName = wbA.name
        fldrpath = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(wbA.name, InStr(wbA.name, "."))
        If Not fso.folderexists(fldrpath) Then
        fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
        End If

    ' Begin the loop.
    For Each wsA In wbA.Sheets
        wsA.Activate

         'create a default name for saving file
          myFile = "R Ch - S " & Year(Date) & " YTD " & tdate & " " & ActiveSheet.name & ".pdf"

            if wsA.name <> "Top 25" and wsA.name <> "Top 10" then
              ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                        Filename:=**ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & myFile, _**
                        (Filename:= fldrpath & myfile, _)
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                        OpenAfterPublish:=False
                With ActiveSheet
    CF = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), 
         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,
         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    CV = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), 
         LookIn:=xlValues, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, 
         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    RF = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), 
         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,
         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    RV = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"),
         LookIn:=xlValues, _
         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,

         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

                   Col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(CF, CV)
                   Rw = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(RF, RV)

                   .PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
                   .PageSetup.Zoom = False
                   .PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
                   .PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
                   .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:" & Cells(Rw, Col).Address
                End With
            End if

         Next wsA
    response = MsgBox(prompt:="PDF's created and saved", Buttons:=vbOKOnly, Title:="Exported to PDF and saved in new folder")
```

Comment: Please tell in which line you get the error.

Comment: I get the error in the save as section of the code, it occurs on the filename line I guess since the code does work when I change this line to Activeworkbook & "\" & myFile (but I want it to be directed to fldrpath not activeworkbook.path. Also I tested this code on another excel. In that file te loop works correctly, but it still won't save under the new folder. So I really don't understand why it won't work now, when it did in the past.

Comment: Go through your code step by step using F8 and check the values of all the variables (in the line of error). Then [edit] your question and include the values of the variables there.